Redirect/confirm not working for django web app registration
Working on the Corey Schafer django tutorials, and I've built a registration page that is supposed to redirect you to the home page once you have signed up for the app and then display a confirmation message. However now, I enter my details, and it doesn't redirect or clear the data.
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Account created for {username}!')
            return redirect('newsfeed')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})

{% if messages %}
  {% for message in messages %}
     <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">
        {{ message }}
     </div>
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}

{% extends "newsfeed/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset>
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Join Today</legend>
                {{  form.as_p  }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <buttom class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Sign Up</buttom>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div class="border-top pt=3">
            <small class="text-muted">
                Already have an account? <a class="ml-2" href="#">Sign In</a>
            </small>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('register/', user_views.register),
    path('', include('newsfeed.urls'))
]

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='newsfeed'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='about'),
]

I think that those are all of the relevant code snippets
The code is for a registration page for my web app, where they enter there details, and then are redirected to the main page (newsfeed) and are greeted with a green banner message confirming that they have registered as a new user.
I've checked all of my paths and I believe that they are correct. My real issue is figuring out where the issue is as there is no syntax error.

You haven't explained the problem.  Tell us what this code actually does, and tell us what you expected to happen instead.

return redirect('') Why are you calling redirect with an empty string?  What do you expect that to do?

apologies, that should contain newsfeed

At a guess, it's because the form had errors (i.e. form.is_valid() was not true), therefore the form is displayed again, giving the user a chance to correct the errors.

do you have any idea how I may be able to fix that? I've done a few searches but no answers have really helped? Thank you for the guidance tho anyway!

You're using form.as_p to show the form, which should also show errors if there were any.  Do you see any errors when the form is redisplayed after submitting?

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

@JohnGordon when I have my command prompt open at the same time as trying to submit my form, there are no changes on the site or on the command line.

@furas when I use 'print()' should the output appear in the command line?

All fixed now! Thank you very much for your help!
